# Как сделать пулю, которая при попадании в игрока пролетает дальше?

Tags: c#, unity3d, разработка-игр

Казалось бы, можно сделать пулю триггером. Но я не могу. Я пытался делать рикошет пули, когда она была триггером, и у меня не получалось. После неудачных решений в плане создания рикошета я сделал пулю НЕ триггером и написал простенький метод рикошета от стен (`collider.gameObject.tag == "Wall"`).

Получается я НЕ могу сделать пулю триггером, так как метод рикошета работает только с пулями, НЕ являющимися триггерами. (Если вы "подгоните" мне рабочий метод, который меняет `velocity` у RigidBody2D при `OnTriggerEnter2D()` для пули в виде рикошета, то я буду очень рад)

В общем... Так как я не могу сделать пулю триггером, я начал баловаться со слоями. Я настроил слои в "*Edit->Project Setting...->Physics 2D->Layer Collision Matrix*" так, чтобы слой пули (`Bullet`) игнорировал слой игроков (`Player`). Ура! Пули проходят сквозь игроков! Но... `OnTrigger(Enter/Exit)2D` и `OnCollision(Enter/Exit)2D` не работают, ведь не видят пересечения и столкновения пулей и игроков. А пересечения они не видят потому, что в "*Layer Collision Matrix*" установлено игнорирование слоя пуль слоем игроков *(или наоборот, без разницы, это матрица(таблица))*.

**Короче вопрос вот в чём:**

Как сделать так, чтобы пуля могла пронзить игроков сколько угодно раз? Пуля не должна быть триггером. Игрок не должен быть триггером.

**Возможное решение, которое я придумал:**

Слои пули и игрока "видят" друг друга и могут сталкиваться. Каждый кадр из пули выпускать луч, длина которого равна расстоянию, которое пуля должна преодолеть за следующий кадр. Если пуля замечает лучём игрока, то выполняется команда `Physics2D.IgnoreCollision(bulletCollider, playerCollider)` и выполняется соответствующий метод а-ля замена `OnCollisionEnter2D`. После выхода из текущего игрока (проверка с помощью того же луча) можно опять использовать метод `IgnoreCollision`, но с третим значением `false`, чтобы коллайдеры друг друга НЕ игнорировали.

Мне не нравится это решение тем, что оно какое-то... Громоздкое и некрасивое?

Comment: если ты пускаешь рейкаст на длину пути за кадр... то нахрена пуле нужен коллайдер? и просто записывать коллайдеры тех, по кому уже нанесен урон в хешсет до следующего рикашета, где сет очищается. через raycastall можно обрабатывать все столкновения по очереди и скорость не важна. и кастить можно не только лучи, но и сферу.

Comment: @Yaroslav коллайдер нужен для рикошета. У меня рикошет определяется вот так: `Direction = Vector2.Reflect(Direction, collision.contacts[0].normal)` при вызове метода `OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)`. Я пытался сделать рикошет лучами, но ничего не получалось. Либо криво работал Reflect, либо криво работало определение нормали поверхности коллайдера, в который попадает луч.

Comment: если коллайдер нужен тебе для этого, то он не нужен вовсе, кривой твой код, с нормалями и Reflect все нормально. `Debug.DrawLine()` тебе в помощь